# pandas to_excel() nothings happens and no error

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, store

I try to use .to_excel(). No error and nothing at all happens, ie the target file "test500.xlsx" stays empty:

```
df_Refined_I = pd.read_excel('/Users/QW/Documents/HH Project/Pilot.xlsx','Refined I')

df_Refined_I.to_excel("test500.xlsx")
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Try both showing the `.head()` of the dataframe (it may be empty) and displaying the current working directory with [`print(os.getcwd())`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) (you may not be writing where you expect)

Comment: Great! Both true. I got the path correct now.

Comment: However, adding df_Refined_I.head() in the code gets ignored. But if I execute df_Refined_I.head() in the shell, I works. What's wrong? And yes, the main problem persists, ie the target file "test500.xlsx" remains untouched/empty.

Comment: You need to display it outside of a shell `print(df_Refined_I.head())`; this is because the shell natively runs `print(repr(result))` if not assigned (actually assignment returns `None`, so it does display it, but there's nothing to display)

Comment: Thank you ti7. Got it. Nonetheless, the main problem is that I still cannot write the data frame into an excel file.... Would be VERY appreciated if you had further help.

Comment: hmm.. please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66449217/edit) your post to add as much relevant information as you can. At least include 1) proof that `.head()` shows the dataframe was read 2) if `os.getcwd()` reports the directory you expect 3) what your engine is (likely `openpyxl`) 4) result of simply trying `pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b': [3,4]}).to_excel("test.xlsx")` in a shell - then you can attempt to [Reopen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36415/340590) your post (editing it will automatically enter it into [a queue for this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229474/discussion-between-researcher121-and-ti7).